How to access Wrangler secrets and Cloudflare secrets in Hono, both in the local development and in the deployed Cloudflare environment
I've set secrets using Wrangler and deployed a Hono project on Cloudflare Workers. However, I'm unable to access those secrets both locally and in the deployed environment. How can I access the secrets in Hono?

the env object isn't visible in Hono?

@pierpy yeah , u can't directly access them but have to use the context for that ! It is okay but when dealing with cloudflare workers and prisma we have to setup the prisma client with the db url for the workers , so to the make that work I have to initialise the prisma client for every request or I have make a middleware for that !

like @Tholkappiar said, c.env - which can be accessed from inside a route. app.use("/"... c ).. Worth reading https://hono.dev/docs/getting-started/cloudflare-workers

for local dev, the .dev.vars file is used for secrets.  When you run wrangler dev you will see it checks this file and outputs to logs....

for Cloudflare based secrets, the Wrangler cli tool has a bunch of commands underneath wrangler secret put|delete|list

There is a section on how to use environment variables in Hono's Getting Started docs:
https://hono.dev/docs/getting-started/cloudflare-workers#load-env-when-local-development
I hope this helps.

yeah @Guest , thanks for that ! I later figured that out that , but I also have an another question , how to deploy this in cloudflare and also upload in the GitHub repo ! because if I push this into GitHub the wrangler.toml file which contains the env's will be exposed right , but I should have to upload the wrangler.toml file to GitHub for the project ! And to the note the cloudflare workers don't use the env file things , I have to set the env things in their dashboard for my backend !

You can add wrangler.toml to your .gitignore and create a wrangler.toml.example file that explains the required configuration without revealing any secrets.

the wrangler.toml can be source controlled.  The .dev.vars is the place to write local secrets and that should be in the .gitignore.
